# Having trouble writing a controller class

Tags: c++, sfml

Okay so I'm writing a controller class to expand the SFML joystick library capabilities.  Since the different controllers I want to use for this game have different integer values mapped to different buttons, I want to be able to pass integer values to the class to map these values to buttons I have defined.  As well, SFML can detect whether a button is pressed with `sf::Joystick::isButtonPressed(unsigned int joystick, unsigned int button)`.  However, this only detects if a button is *currently pressed* and thus holding the button will just register as repeated presses.  So I wrote my own code to detect for a button press without a hold.

So here's the issue: What is the proper way for the player (outside the class) to access the set of buttons without exposing data?  I could have getters for the buttons, but then the `buttonPressed` method couldn't change the value of `held`.  The only way I could see this working is if I gave full access to the `Button`'s.  Or should I go about this a different way?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here's the relevant code:

```
// Controller.h

class Controller
{
public:
    struct Button
    {
        unsigned int id;
        bool held;
    };

    // constructor which assigns a controller ID
    // and a set of buttons
    Controller(...); 

    // Checks each frame for each button if 
    // any are not held and sets held to false
    void update();

    bool buttonPressed(Button& button);
private:
    unsigned int controllerId_;
    Button A_, B_, X_, Y_, Z_, R_, L_, 
    START_, D_PAD_UP_, D_PAD_LEFT_, D_PAD_DOWN_, D_PAD_RIGHT_;
};
```

---

```
// Controller.cpp

bool Controller::buttonPressed(Button& button)
{
    if (sf::Joystick::isButtonPressed(controllerId_, button.id) && !button.held)
    {
        button.held = true;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know you can use the [JoystickButtonPressed](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/window-events.php#the-joystickbuttonpressed-and-joystickbuttonreleased-events) event to detect a button press?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way to go here is let the player access the "virtual" key names, and ask for their current state. You would introduce an enum or a set of constants that map your `Button` instances to names that can be accessed. Something like the following would do the job:

```
enum class ButtonName
{
    A, B, X, Y, Z, R, L, START, D_PAD_UP, D_PAD_DOWN, D_PAD_LEFT, D_PAD_RIGHT
};
```

Now, instead of named members, your `Controller` class should store a map (or an array, if the enum values are continuous) that maps the button names to their `Button` representations. So replace your members with `std::map<ButtonName, Button> buttonMappings;`. Now, for initialization, you can either provide an utility method `Controller::MapKey(ButtonName, unsigned int buttonID);`, or perhaps just pass in an `std::map` to the constructor of the `Controller` instance.

Now, the part where the player accesses becomes really nice to the code that needs to check for controller button presses. You can simply call `if (controller.IsButtonPressed(ButtonName::D_PAD_UP)) { ... }`. The implementation for `IsButtonPressed` then simply looks up the `Button` value for the correct name. So something like the following:

```
bool Controller::IsButtonPressed(ButtonName name)
{
    Button& button = buttonMappings.at(name);

    if (sf::Joystick::isButtonPressed(controllerId_, button.id) && !button.held)
    {
        button.held = true;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```